# how to remove code behind CSS using jquery?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

i am using jquery for enabling and disabling a button

```
$(function () {
$('.CSSCheck').click(function () {
    if ($("[id$='Chkbox']:checked").length > 0) {
        $("#<%=Button1.ClientID %>").removeAttr('disabled');
    }
    else {
        $("#<%=Button1.ClientID %>").attr('disabled', 'disabled');

    }
});
});
```

on code behind i am adding a css to datalist image button on Select_Command

```
DataListItemCollection xxx = datalist1.Items;  
int index = id;
int count = 0;     
foreach (DataListItem x in xxx )
{
   if (count == index)
        {
          (x.FindControl("btn1") as ImageButton).BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
          (x.FindControl("btn1") as ImageButton).BorderWidth = 1;
        }
}
```

how to remove this css using the same jquery?

Comment: you mean remove against all button in the List or just specific one?

Comment: removing from the selected one, because my code behind css is getting applied in a particular image button(which is selected), how could i make my blue color to white through using my jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work

```
$("#<%=Button1.ClientID %>").css('border', '');
```

It is recommended however to use classes

```
$("#<%=Button1.ClientID %>").removeClass('myborder');
```

in code-behind:

```
(x.FindControl("btn1") as ImageButton).CssClass = "myborder";
```

Style definition:

```
.myborder { border: 1px solid Blue; }
```

Comment: Button1 is different (its out side of datalist), and btn1 is different(its inside the datalist)

Comment: You can change jQuery selector to search for buttons with class assigned from code-behind: `$(".myborder").removeClass('myborder');`